# ContourPlot has weird wavy line

Tags: plotting

I have been using ContourPlot for a complicated but analytic function, which does not need numerical calculations. I am confused to see the result looks like the following picture, where the lines which should be straight are wavy. Is here some problems with the plot steps or anything else?

The code is about

```
ContourPlot[f[a,b,x,y]==f[a,b,g[a],0],{gae, 10^-3, 100}, {gag, 10^-6, 1}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
```

where f is an analytic but complicated function of variables a, b, x, y, while g[a] is a interpolation function of variable a. Moreover, in my plot variables a and b are fixed.

[image: ContourPlot]

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code along with the image so that people can play around with it and see if they can solve the problem! :)

Comment: But, this definitely looks numerical to me. Try something like `PlotPoints -> 300` (or more)?

Comment: @thorimur Thank you for your advice, and it is really useful! I realize that I may ask a trivial question. Perhaps the ContourPlot uses numerical methods to find the boundary? Or maybe it is due to there are interpolation functions among my plotting function.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mma.S.E. As it has already been pointed out, please add the code that can reproduce this issue or a minimal working example. In such a way it's going to be much easier for us to grab the code and try to suggest ways to fix it. Many thanks!

Comment: Also btw, thanks for posting some of the code, but in the future we do actually need *all* of the code! It should be totally self-contained. The point of having code is so people can copy-paste it into their own notebooks, hit shift+enter, modify it, and try to adjust the output until it works. If there are missing pieces, like `f`, people probably won't be able to help as effectively! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved after I add `PlotPoints -> 300` thanks to @thorimur.

Perhaps the problem is due to the interpolation function g[a] or due to the plotting methods of ContourPlot itself.

[image]

Comment: I would be nice to cite the author of the comment who provided this idea.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Rather than using very large values of `PlotPoints`, a smaller increase in `PlotPoints` can be used by also specifying a value for `MaxRecursion` (e.g., `MaxRecursion -> 5`). This is often more efficient. However, without sufficient code to reproduce your results we can only guess at what might be best.